# Can I use VLOOKUP to join data in my Excel document?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

My excel document has two sheets, sheet 1 has the names of car manufacturers on it and sheet 2 has those same names with their relative ID (this is a database that it's taken from).

Sheet 1

```
Name
Ford
Accura
Holden
```

Sheet 2

```
Id    Name
1     Ford
2     Accura
3     Holden
```

I'd like to be able to lookup sheet to and match the strings to get the Id of the car manufacturer from it.  I tried using VLOOKUP but I cannot get it to work.

Let's assume that on Sheet1 the name column is D2 (not including title of course) and that the sheet I want to lookup is called "CarMakes" in which the data is B3:C17 (not including titles)

I wrote my vlookup in the following way:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,CarMakes!B3:C17,2,TRUE)
```

However, this gives me a result of '#N/A' so I think my approach is wrong.  Can anyone help me with this and is vlookup the right way to do it?  Also, can I perform these sam operations by connecting to my database which is in Azure?

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` will not work in this case because `VLOOKUP()` always lookup to first column of table. But lookup data in 2nd column. Try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need `INDEX()/MATCH()`

```
=INDEX(CarMakes!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(A2,CarMakes!$B$2:$B$4,0))
```

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then can try `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,CarMakes!$B$2:$B$10,CarMakes!$A$2:$A$10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use $ before coordinate

=VLOOKUP(D2,CarMakes!$B$3:$C$17,2,TRUE)

That should help.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` will not work in this case because `VLOOKUP()` always lookup to first column of table. But OP looking up to 2nd column.

Comment: Yes Harun24HR you are right.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-n-a-error-in-the-vlookup-function-e037d763-ffc3-4fae-a909-89c482d389b2